# Convergence of Modified Sequence of Random Variables to Different Distribution

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, random-variable, poisson-distribution, convergence

I am self-studying for a qualifying exam later this summer and would like someone to check over my proof; I feel like I may have "cheated" somewhere...

**The Question:**

Suppose that $X$ has a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda>0$ and that $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables such that $X_n \xrightarrow{d} X$ as $n\xrightarrow{}\infty$. Is it necessarily true that

$\sqrt{n}(X_n-\lambda)\xrightarrow{d}N(0, \lambda)$

Provide details in support of your claim or a counterexample.

**Solution Attempt (Counterexample):**

Let $0<\lambda<\infty$. Put $X_n = X$ $\forall n$. Then, trivially, $X_n \xrightarrow{d} X$

Now, for any fixed $n'$, we have

$$ \begin{align}
Var[\sqrt{n'}(X_{n'}-\lambda)] & = Var(X_{n'}\sqrt{n'} - \lambda\sqrt{n'}) \\
& = Var(X_{n'}\sqrt{n'}) + Var(\lambda\sqrt{n'}) \\
& = n'Var(X_{n'}) + 0 \\
& = n'Var(X) \\
& = n'\lambda > 0
\end{align} $$

Notice that as $n' \xrightarrow{} \infty$, $n'\lambda \xrightarrow{} \infty$. Therefore, the variance of the expression goes to infinity. Since it does not converge to $\lambda$, there is no way that $\sqrt{n}(X_n-\lambda)$ converges in distribution to $N(0, \lambda)$. $\blacksquare$

Any suggestions or corrections would also be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the self study tag.

Comment: In light of your idea to set $X_n=X,$ all you need to do is show that no affine transformation of a Poisson distribution can be Normal, and that is obvious because the former is discrete while the latter is continuous.